# Spatial features and pattern analysis of a plan?

Tags: matlab, spatial

I am working on instances from the TSPLIB, which are simply coordinates of nodes in a plan. I'm looking to analyze spatial characteristics and features of a set of instances (e.g. clustered, not clustered, dispersed, etc) and I would like to implement some code in Matlab to analyze and compute specific features.

For example, so far, I have used Nearest Neighbor analysis to identify clusters, as well as quadrant analysis. Can anyone suggest any other spatial features and patterns that could be computed with some relatively simple code? Anybody maybe expert in the Traveling Salesman Problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

K-means is a very useful clustering tool that you can use.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html

Nearest Neighbor is a classification methods. if you want to do classification you can use K Nearest Neighbors, SVM or Neural Networks Pattern recognition toolbox. these are all already in Matlab.

Also, check out Matlab Apps. there are some very cool clustering tools available as well with examples.